# regex to find the any special character in a word by using python

Tags: python, regex

Is there any comprehensive regex that will identify all kind of special charatcers from a word, or in other words i need a regex for python that will identify any charater from a word other than a letter (a-z or A-Z) and numbers(0-9).

Comment: Use a negated character class, `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` ..

Comment: simple `[^A-Za-z0-9]`

Comment: `''.join(char for char in myString if not char.isalnum())` <- not a regex, but still!

Comment: [^a-zA-Z0-9] woked well

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if re.search("[^a-z0-9]", string, re.IGNORECASE):
    # Successful match
else:
    # Match attempt fail
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vQ8dX4/1)

Explanation:

```
[^a-z0-9]
---------

Options: Case insensitive;

Match any single character NOT present in the list below «[^a-z0-9]»
   A character in the range between “a” and “z” (case insensitive for A-Z) «a-z»
   A character in the range between “0” and “9” «0-9»
```